# OCI Error: LNK1113: invalid machine type

Tags: c, oracle11g, linker-errors, oracle-call-interface

I'm calling OCI apis to connect the oracle database. I have installed instant client for the same and all oracle server-client configuration setup is ready.

I have written a sample C application (win32 console application) to test the oci apis.
Set following parameters in the **project settings**,

```
include path: $(ORACLE_HOME)\oci\include
library linker path: $(ORACLE_HOME)\oci\lib\msvc
library: oci.lib
```

While building an application it is giving a **linker error**,

```
\oci\lib\msvc\oci.lib : fatal error LNK1113: invalid machine type
```

Using,

```
Machine: 64-bit 
Application: 32-bit
Editor: Visual Studio C++ 6.0
Oracle Version: Oracle11g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.
Was linking 64-bit library with 32-bit application.
Should install 32-bit OCI library to work on 32-bit application.